# Image Annotation for the respective image how can i overcome the issue

Tags: python, opencv

Can I get a code of image annotation in openCV python to predict the specific object in an image?

Answer (score 0):

You can search for LabelImg 's github. I usually use this one. The annotations for object recognition have to be done manually.
Another option is FIAT but I have never used it.